# Running only a specific Spec from SBT that has constructor parameters

Tags: scala, sbt, specs2

I have a [specs2](/questions/tagged/specs2) `Specification` to test database related things against multiple databases. Therefore it gets the database configuration to test against via its constructor parameters. It is instantiated and used from a bigger spec which tests against all the databases.

Now I only want to test against lets say MSSQL in sbt but if I use `test-only f.q.d.n.MySpec(DatabaseConfig.MSSQL)` no tests are run because it does not match any tests. If I leave the parameter off it tries to instantiate the class and rightfully fails because it cant instantiate it without parameters.

Is there a way to only run a specific specification with a specific set of constructor parameters from sbt without changing the bigger spec that calls it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `test:only` you need to pass an expression matching the class name (using `*` if needed). Then specs2 will try to instantiate your constructor parameters if they have a constructor with 0 arguments. This is not the case if you pass an object. Can you try to a have class with a 0 argument constructor instead?

Comment: I know that the `class` could be rewritten to take no parameters and then use it with `test-only`, but I was wondering if there is a way to use it as is.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Your specification class can have one parameter. But its type must be a class having a no-parameter constructor. That being said there is no way to pass this parameter from the command line if this is really what you are after.

Comment: Reading your answer again I see that I have missed that part. If there is no way to pass a parameter from the command line this answers my question.